# (appmaker) Correctly setting up a multiselect

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having trouble correctly setting up a multiselect so that I can edit the data in my app. More specifically, I'm creating a form so that you can edit the details of a Client, including their favorite foods. I want to have a multiselect in that form where you can see the list of checked favorite foods across a list of allowable foods (as determined by one of the fields in the Food model).

For my data model, I have a one-to-many relation between "Clients" (one, from the Client model) and "Favorite Foods" (many, from the Food model).

The problem I'm having is that the `options` field for a multiselect ends up being a `List<String>` (`@model.Food.fields.Name.possibleValues`). However, I can't figure out what I need to put in the `values` field. My inclination is to want to be able to put `@datasource.item.FavoriteFoods` but I can't end up choosing that, presumably because it's `List<Food record>` and not a `List<String>` result. (That assumption could be wrong, I don't know why I can't select that.)

Anyone know how you're supposed to actually do this? I'm more sure my `options` selection is the right way to put the list of options, so I think I just don't know what's normal to put in the `values` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your problem description, this is what I've done...

I created a model named **clients** and a model named **favoriteFoods**.
Then I set up the relation **clients**(ONE) - (MANY) **favoriteFoods**.

Next. I created some test **favoriteFoods** records and some test **clients** records. 
Then in a test page I inserted an edit form with the datasource being **clients**. 
This is how it looks:

[image]

I had to manually insert the **multiselect** widget because it was not available by default. Then I set up the **multiselect** bindings as follows:

**options**: *@datasources.favoriteFoods.items*
**values**: *@datasource.item.favoriteFoods*

Finally, preview the app and you should be able to see the following behavior:

[image]

P.S.  If the widget was already inserted before you created the relations or models, chances are that you need to delete the widget and insert it again. I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please share what software you use for your video clips? I've seen others that you have put together like this and have wondered about this since I was thinking about putting together some instructional videos myself.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Of course! I got it for $49 but I just found out there is special offer and you can get it for $29 https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/techradar/. When it comes to appmaker, it makes more sense if you put some screen shots and videos right? :)